# Pinescript print a straight line in session with vwap close from session before

Tags: pine-script

Im clueless how to use vwap in pinescript, my use case is:

Print a straight line for the day with the value of VWAP close from yesterday.

```
study(title="Volume-weighted average example", overlay=true)

// Calculate moving average
vwapValue = vwap(close)

// Plot value
plot(series=vwapValue, color=teal, linewidth=2, trackprice=true)
```

This is just very basic what I have but I have no clue how to get the value of the close for the last day and print it like I described as a horizontal line spanning from session open to session end. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We can use this evaluation to determine if we're on the first bar of a new day

```
newDay = change(time("D")) != 0
```

Using `valuewhen()` we can obtain when the last time `newDay` was true and get the vwap's value from the prior bar `vwap[1]` (which would be the last/closing value of the vwap from the previous day).

```
vwapClose = valuewhen(newDay, vwap[1], 0)

plot(vwap, color = color.red)
plot(vwapClose, color = color.blue)
```