# How to plot last value of VWAP for each given period?

Tags: pine-script

#### Description

I would like to plot a horizontal ray from the end of each Anchored VWAP for the Daily, Weekly, Monthly time periods, and ending when price action returns to the level (i.e., each naked VWAP).

The sample script I have for this is here:

```
//@version=5
indicator("nVWAP(s)", overlay=true)

newWeek = ta.change(time("W")) != 0

vwap_w = ta.vwap(open, timeframe.change("1W"))
wvwapClose = ta.valuewhen(newWeek, vwap_w[1], 0)
plot(wvwapClose, color = color.blue)
plot(vwap_w, color = color.blue)
```

#### Problem

The problem is that the line only extends until the next time period and then prints vertical to the next one. I am not sure how to get the lines to print and end when price action revisits that value, and without printing vertical from period to period.

It needs to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWuDR.png) (an example from a different indicator). Notice that only the lines that have not been revisited are showing. Although I would like to be able to toggle it like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1daa.png), but that might be out of scope for this question.

#### Reference Material

- [VWAP Market Session Anchored](https://www.tradingview.com/script/zNkHo9a3-VWAP-Market-Session-Anchored/) which helped me understand how to plot intra-day anchored VWAPs and why I have use different logic for longer time periods.
- [Pine Script™ language reference manual](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_ta%7Bdot%7Dvwap) for basic anchored VWAP plotting for Daily, Weekly, Monthly time periods.
- I studied the [Multi-Time Period Charts](https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?solution=43000502591) indicator script which eventually got me on the track of trying to use the `ta.change()` function but I ran into issues when trying to use the `plot()` function inside an `if` statement.
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69046028/pinescript-print-a-straight-line-in-session-with-vwap-close-from-session-before) stackoverflow question/answer showed me how to use the `ta.change` function for plotting the VWAP closing values.
- I also figured out I can't simply index the last value of the series returned by `ta.vwap()` with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73639276/how-to-get-only-the-last-value-of-the-series-output-of-an-expression) stackoverflow question/answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be done with `line` function:

```
//@version=5
indicator("nVWAP(s)", overlay=true)

newWeek = ta.change(time("W")) != 0

vwap_w = ta.vwap(open, timeframe.change("1W"))
wvwapClose = ta.valuewhen(newWeek, vwap_w[1], 0)

numberOfBarsInWeek = ta.valuewhen(newWeek, bar_index, 0) - ta.valuewhen(newWeek, bar_index, 1)

if newWeek
    vwap_w_line = line.new(bar_index, vwap_w, bar_index + numberOfBarsInWeek, vwap_w, color = color.aqua)
    wvwapClose_line = line.new(bar_index, wvwapClose, bar_index + numberOfBarsInWeek, wvwapClose, color = color.orange)
```